# Kohana3 ORM: loading Key/Value Attributes

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana-3

I have two MySQL-Tables (oversimplified):

```
articles
- id
- description

article_attributes
- article_id
- attribute_name
- attribute_value
```

So, every `article` can have an unlimited amount of `attributes`.
For the `articles` i have a Kohana_ORM Model

```
<?php class Model_Article extends ORM {} ?>
```

When loading the Model I would like to have access to all the attributes.

Example:

```
<?php
$article = new Model_Article(1); // or ORM::factory('article', 1);
echo $article->description;
echo $article->attribute->foo;
echo $article->attribute->bar;
?>
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction how to achive this?

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need to create 2 model, one for each table, then define the relationship between them.

Try this,

```
class Model_Article extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array('attributes' => array());
}

class Model_Atribute extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'article_attributes';
    protected $_belongs_to = array('article' => array());
}
```

Then you can do this,

```
$article = ORM::factory('article', 1);
$article_attributes = $article->attributes->find_all();
```

I don't know if you solved this issue or not, but I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [Kohana ORM guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5022685/Kohana-PHP-ORM-Guide-Volume-1-). It treats one to one, one to many (your case) and many to many relationships. I didn't copy pasted the code in here because there is quite a bit.